# Yellow orange box with dot in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I don't know what I have clicked while I was coding, but this orange box with dots appeared hiding my code:

[image]

How can I make my code visible again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You clicked the arrow on the left, just click it again to collapse the code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You activated the Code Folding feature. This allows you to hide a block of text temporarily so that you can concentrate on the surrounding lines. The ellipsis (three dots) in the orange box indicates that there are hidden lines at that point in the buffer.

One way to show all lines is with menu item **Edit** > **Code Folding** > **Unfold All**. You may also want to explore the other items in that submenu.